# flickering when resizing my processing canvas using swing components

Tags: java, swing, processing, rcp

I have written a RCP platform (swing components) that displays a bar Graph drawn in processing. When I manually resize the frame, flickering occurs. I would like to find out how to keep this from happening.

Answer (score 1):

Processing and Swing don’t mix well. Have a look at the discussions on the [Processing Forum](https://forum.processing.org/search/swing).

Comment: It is not up to me to make that choice. I would like to solve the problem as it stands

Comment: System.setProperty("sun.awt.noerasebackground", "true"); seems to work against the flickering. I just need a way to contain it only to the bit im sketching on